# Distance from a point to a set in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is a closed set. Show that given any $a \in \mathbb{R^n}$, there exists $x_{0} \in Y$ such that $|x_{0}−a| ≤ |x−a|$ for all $x \in Y$.

let's remember that: "we define the distance of a point $a \in \mathbb{R^n}$ to a set $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ as the number $d(a,Y)=$ $\inf$ {$|x-a|:x \in Y$}"

The idea I had was that:

If $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is closed, then for any $a \in \mathbb{R^n}$, the function $f:Y → \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=|x-a|$ assumes its minimum value at some point $_{0} \in Y$; so there is $d(a,Y)=|x_{0}-a|$.

but I must do it by sequences and not functions, then I would not know how to do it

Comment: Do you have the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) (for continuous functions on closed sets)?

Comment: @EricTowers no, I can only use the definitions of sequences, open and closed ball and the definition of distance that I put in the statement

Answer (score 1):

By definition of infimum of a  set $d(a,Y)$ can be written as $\lim |a-x_i|$ for some sequence $(x_i) \subseteq Y$. This implies that $(a-x_i)$ is bounded and hence $(x_i)$ is also bounded. There is a subsequence of $x_i$ which is convergent. Take $x_0$ to the limit of this subsequence.